# How to assign a List<List<String>> variable to a empty list in java?

Tags: java, collections, empty-list

I have a line of code

```
List<List<String>> get_valuesofValues = new ArrayList<List<String>>((Collection<? extends List<String>>)map.get(value_atIndex));
```

"get_valuesofValues"  will be null in some places. How can I assign it to a empty list in order to avoid exception?

Should be something like this :

```
if(get_valuesofValues  == null){
                get_valuesofValues =((Collection.<List<String>>)emptyList();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.emptyList()` method. Please note, that such collections cannot be modified (add/replace/remove of elements produces an exception).